# jquery - get mouse coordinates within a function

Tags: jquery, coordinates, mouseover, mousemove

I can get the coordinates within `$(document).ready(function() { $(id).mouemove(function(){}) };`

But what if I want to get the coordinates right in a function?

```
<div id='abc' onmouseover="callFunction(this.id)"></div>
```

I only get undefined. Why?

```
function callFunction(arg){
   mouseX = arg.pageX; 
   mouseY = arg.pageY;

   alert('--> ' + mouseX + ' - ' + mouseY);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div id='abc' onmouseover="callFunction(event)">123</div>`

```
function callFunction(e){
console.log(e);
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;

    alert('--> ' + mouseX + ' - ' + mouseY);
}
```